# My Google App Engine appspot URL wont work

Tags: google-app-engine

I recently created my Google App Engine account, and uploaded my application, and have an instance of said app running.

I can access my app via localhost:8080 but when I try to use myappid.appspot.com I get a 500 Server Error (Of course I replace "myappid" with my apps name). This is what it says:

"Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it."

Can anyone help me get the URL working? I need my team to be able to access this app from anywhere. I have no idea what could be wrong with it, I am very new to GAE. After a lot of searching all I find is people saying their appspot URL works, and want other options. But I just want my appspot URL to work first!

Some more info:

This is a Python app, using the GAE Python SDK, I am running Windows 7, and using the GAE Launcher GUI to deploy and run the app.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the error in my Log:

: No module named flask Traceback (most recent call last): File "/base/data/home/apps/s~luxtestapp/1.362824400913245138/bootstrap.py", line 19, in  from app import create_app File "/base/data/home/apps/s~luxtestapp/1.362824400913245138/app/**init**.py", line 10, in  from flask import Flask

Apparently the app uses Flask instead of Webbapp2. Honestly I'm not too sure about it all, because this is a pre-built app that I downloaded and deployed. I didn't write it.

Comment: You can't use flask on AppEngine unless you provide the source code.

Answer (score 0):

In the control panel for your app on appspot go to the log section.

[Appengine](https://appengine.google.com)

The see what the latest entry says. Filter to "error".

Also when you create your app (python webapp2 example) turn debugging on:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)], 
    debug=True)
```

You'll get a much more informative error screen then instead of '500'.

Comment: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~luxtestapp/1.362824400913245138/bootstrap.py", line 19, in <module>
    from app import create_app
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~luxtestapp/1.362824400913245138/app/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from flask import Flask

Comment: That is the last error I see in the log, I can post more info if needed. The character limit in these replies stopped me from pasting all of it. I think that is the important part though.

Comment: Also, sorry to be a noob, but can you be more specific about where I would turn debugging on? I am just deploying and running a pre-built app, that I downloaded. So I didn't write it, or really know where to turn on debugging.

Comment: It looks like you are using Flask. Flask is something I use only when I can't use GAE. If you really want to do it then apparently it's possible but I can't help you I'm afraid. Found this, http://mostovenko.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/launching-flask-on-google-app-engine-gae.html but suggest you might consider rewrite in webapp2? http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/

Comment: Don't know I'm afraid. If it does not look like my example because it's some special setup for flask I can't help I'm afraid. I know about them as separate things.

Comment: Thanks for your help though, at least now I know there is a difference between webapp2 and flask, and that my app uses flask. And with your link I'm getting closer to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the flask folder to your project folder. In general every package not supported by GAE (see list of [supported libraries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)), must be present in the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the environment variables before/after deploy. Go to the local project folder, open bash the paste this commands: ps: Ignore the $ sign

$ set HTTP_PROXY=http://cache.example.com:3128
$ set HTTPS_PROXY=http://cache.example.com:3128

check this link out for help: cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp